# iOS Notification Behavior when setting is OFF in device level

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, apple-push-notifications

What is the expected behaviour of [userNotificationCenter:willPresentNotification:withCompletionHandler:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate/1649518-usernotificationcenter?language=objc)
when the notification setting for an app is turned OFF in device level? I always assumed no callback will be called if setting is OFF but I am observing in my app that this callback is hitting the breakpoint even when device setting is OFF. Apple doc does not mention anything on the expected behaviour so wondering if anyone here knows what is expected  or if this is an iOS bug.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's expected behavior and it is what you should expect. Let's tease it apart like this.

- The *user* has said they do not want to *see* any evidence of notifications (alerts, banners, sounds, badges). But that does not mean that no notifications *exist* — the user has no ability to reach into the system and switch off the user notification center itself! So the notification center is still operative, and the notification, *qua* signal, still has the ability to arrive.
- Very well, so indeed the user is not *going* see any alerts, banners, sounds, or badges. What's happening is merely that the notification *qua* signal has arrived, as we agreed in the previous point. And your app happens to be frontmost, and is thus in a position to *hear about* the fact that the notification signal arrived.

  And why shouldn't your app hear about this? Your app is not going to violate the user's wishes by presenting any notification alerts, banners, etc.; it cannot do so in any case. But it can still *respond* to the notification. There is no reason why the user should be permitted to reach into your app and *lame* it by preventing news of its own notifications from reaching it, any more than the user should be permitted to crush the operation of the user notification center.

Comment: That's a well detailed response, thanks! I forgot the part that my app won't  display the notification as you pointed out in the first bullet.

Comment: Well I thought it was an insightful and well prepared question too!